# How do you recall an item from a list based on it's index position?

Tags: python

I'm attempting to recall an item from a list based on it's index position, and the index position part is important part because in my script the user types in an input and then it's converted into a list and then I want to re-integrate the input into a final print statement. Here's some example code.

```
print("Star Wars is a [adjective] story of [noun] vs Sith")
swinput = list(swinput.split())
```

let's say the user input great and Jedi

I would want the output to look like: `Star Wars is a great story of Jedi vs Sith`

The key piece that I can't get is that regardless of what the user inputs it will show up in the print statement and I can't figure that piece out so any help as always is greatly appreciated!

Comment: please post the full code of what you've tried.

Comment: you print before you get input and you don't use your input, so maybe work on that =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your information this is what I understood. Tell me if I forgot something.

```
l = ["word1","word2"]
print(f'this is {l[0]} and this is {l[1]}')
```

Is this what you are asking for?

Comment: Ahhh the curly braces is what I was missing thank you

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're trying to replace the [adjective] and [noun] parts of that sentence based on some variables. You might want to check out the [format method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format). With it, you can do stuff like this:

```
def format_quote(adjective, noun):
    return "Star Wars is a {} story of {} vs Sith".format(adjective, noun)
```

or, in Python 3.6 or later, you can use [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/):

```
def format_quote(adjective, noun):
    return f"Star Wars is a {adjective} story of {noun} vs Sith"
```